# Relay files received through multipart/form-data using GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, guzzle

I have an image received through jQuery ajax as a POST and I need to send it to another API endpoint by using GuzzleHttp.

```html
<input name="image-to-upload" type="file" accept="image/*" id="image-to-upload">
```

```js
$('input[type="file"]').on('change', function (event) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("images", event.target.files[0], 'image.jpg');

    $.ajax({
        data: formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        timeout: 60000,
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://example.com/my-endpoint/',
        xhr: function () {
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
    });
});
```

My end:

```php
<?php
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'http://example.com/']);
$res = $client->request('POST', 'another-endpoint/', [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'images',
            'contents' => $_FILES['images'],
            'filename' => 'filename.jpg'
        ],
    ],
]);
```

What I'm possibly doing wrong to get an ***Unexpected field*** error from the **"another-endpoint"**?

Comment: Not sure how it works in guzzle, but try using `'contents' => $_FILES['images']['tmp_name']`, which is the path to the actual uploaded file. Or if it needs the actual content of the file and not just the path, try: `'contents' => file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])`

Comment: does the another endpoint has fields name as images to be given when sending post request?

Comment: Also what type of data is there inside is it a temp file path or a raw data

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried that too without any luck.

Comment: @bhucho yes the "another-endpoint" has a field name called "images". And the raw data is carrying an image.

Comment: can you show here `print_r($_FILES['images'])`, also have you tried sending some normal image that is already in your file system using `fopen()` then we can know if the error is due to name field or contents field

Comment: Hi @MagnusEriksson and @bhucho it worked with `file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name'])`. It was an issue at the "another-endpoint". Thanks for your support. I'm new to StackOverflow. How should I close the issue?

Comment: It will close automatically after 2-3 days